# get JSON Parameters PHP

Tags: php, json

I am new to JSON and I am facing some difficulties , i am doing an `echo $response;` and i am getting:

```
    { "items": [ { "tableName": "CO.Affected_Country", "count": 1, "columnNames": [ "id" ], "rows": [ [ "12" ] ] } ], "links": [ { "rel": "self", "href": "https://ter.ge.com/services/rest/connect/v1.3/queryResults?query=x" }, { "rel": "canonical", "href": "x" }, { "rel": "describedby", "href": "x", "mediaType": "application/schema+json" } ] }
```

i am trying to get the 'row' value , so i am trying to use `$response->{"items"}->{"row"};` I know this syntax is wrong , but how can i do it?

Comment: $obj = json_decode($json);

Comment: https://eval.in/618363  .And now you have array so iterate on it and get your desired data.  like this:- https://eval.in/618368

Comment: $data = json_decode($response, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$obj = json_decode($response);
$rows = $obj->items[0]->rows[0];
```

This is an array.  To get the first value (12), you can then do:

```
echo $rows[0]
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Q4I0E)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$data = json_decode($response);
echo $data["items"][0]["tableName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode($response)` so:

```
$data = json_decode($response);
$data->items->row; // or $data['items']['row']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **json_decode($response)** to use json as an object

```
$data = json_decode($response);
```

or
if you want to use it as array, put `true` after reponse variable

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);

echo $data["items"][0]["tableName"];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!